# IE indents table within a table properly but Firefox doesn't

Tags: html

I thought that the problem might be with the &nbsp so I was playing around with   that    for a while but that didn't fix it. I assume IE is either ignoring incorrect code and that is why it looks correct on IE

```
  <TABLE CLASS=cTable BORDER=1 CELLPADDING=4 CELLSPACING=0 width=50%>
  <TR>
     <TH 
     class=TH1 colspan=3>Hours Summary for 04/17/2011 - 04/30/2011
     </TH>
     <TH class=TH1>

  </TR>
  <TR>
      <TH>
      Cost Center
      </TH>
  <TH>
      Cost Center Name<br> <font size = '1'>Cost Center Owner</font>
  </TH>
  <TH>
      Completion<br>Status
  </TH>
  <TH>
      Approval<br>Status
  </TH>
  </TR>


  <TR CLASS='cTableAltTD' >
      <TD 
      align='center'><a href='javascript:ToggleDisplay("tr427200");'>427200</a>
      </TD>
      <TD 
       align='center'>MEDCTR-NON MED CENTER APPROVERS<br>HARRISON,RODNEY STEVEN
      </TD>
      <TD 
       align='center'><IMG SRC='Art/CircleRed.gif' 
       BORDER=0 HEIGHT=16 WIDTH=16 ALT='Does not meet Min Requirement'>
      </TD>
      <TD 
       align='center'><IMG SRC='Art/CircleRed.gif' 
       BORDER=0 HEIGHT=16 WIDTH=16 ALT='Does not meet Min Requirement'>
      </TD>
  </TR>
  <TR id=tr427200 style='display: table'>
      <TD>&nbsp;
      </td>
      <TD colspan=3>
<TABLE CLASS=cTable BORDER=1 CELLPADDING=4 CELLSPACING=0 width=100%> 

<TR>
   <TH class=TH1 colspan=6>
      <TR>
          <TH>
              Timesheet Group
          </TH>
          <TH>
               Primary Approver
          </TH>
          <TH>
              Completion<br>Status
          </TH>
          <TH>
              Approval<br>Status
          </TH>
      </TR>

</TABLE>
```

Comment: FYI the `<font>` tag was deprecated a loooong time ago.

Comment: Yikes, that's really really horrible looking code. This code goes against pretty much every HTML best practice I know. I'm guessing it was written a very long time ago?

Comment: ALL CAPITAL TAGS, `border` properties and the like are awful practice and belong in the nineties. Please update your coding style. _Pleeeease_

Comment: I'd be willing to bet that the problem is that the page doesn't have a valid `<!DOCTYPE>` at the start.

Comment: This is a legacy application from a while ago that I am trying to make compatible with Firefox. Don't shoot me I didn't write it :)